Closure of a closed set in a subspace
I apologize in advance if this question turns out to be a really stupid one, but I just want to make sure I'm on the right track here.
Let $X$ be a topological space, $Y$ a subspace of $X$, and $Z$ a subset of $Y$. Is the closure of $Z$ in $Y$ still defined as the smallest closed subset in $Y$ containing $Z$? In particular, if $Z$ is closed in $Y$, is $Z$ equal to its own closure in $Y$?

The closure of $Z$ in $Y$ does not depend on $X$.

@Lucenaposition Since the closure of $Z$ in $Y$ is equal to the intersection of $Y$ with the closure of $Z$ in $X$, it must depend on $X$ somehow, no?

If $Y$ is a subspace of $X$ then $Y$ has its own topology and you can ignore what the surrounding space $X$ is.

If we are only comparing $Z$ and $Y$, as @Lucenaposition commented, our study does not depend on $X$. Nevertheless, we can ask the following alternative question: Is the closure of $Z$ in $Y$ still the smallest closed subest in $X$ containing $Z$? That is to say, examine whether $\operatorname{cl}_Y(Z)=\operatorname{cl}_X(Z)$ holds. By the identity $\operatorname{cl}_Y(Z)=\operatorname{cl}_X(Z)\cap Y$, it is easy to see that $\operatorname{cl}_Y(Z)\subseteq\operatorname{cl}_X(Z)$. The other inclusion holds if $Y$ is closed in $X$ (it is not a necessary condition).

@Ikeroy - more generally, $\operatorname{cl}_Y(Z)=\operatorname{cl}_X(Z)$ if and only if $\operatorname{cl}_X(Z) \subseteq Y$. If $Y$ is closed in $X$, then this will be true for any $Z \subseteq Y$. Otherwise, there will be some sets $Z$ whose closures in $X$ and $Y$ are the same, and others (in particular, $Z = Y$) where the closures differ.
